# Saving Django data from forms to sqlite database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

What I have here is basically recipes which have to be saved in a database with many to one relationship between hops, fermentables etc. and main recipe which includes the name type and so on.

What we have is the user fills in the forms and then with this information we are calling this in the `view.py` file:

```
def saveRecipe(request):
        try:
            data=json.loads(request.read())
            recipe = Recipes.create(attr=data)
            recipe.name = data["name"]
            recipe.addYeast(items=data["yeast"])
            recipe.addFermentables(items=data["fermentables"])
            recipe.addHops(items=data["hops"])
            recipe.addMashStep(items=data["mash"])
            return  HttpResponse(serialize('json', [recipe]),  content_type='application/json')
        except:
           
            return HttpResponse("error")
```

Now this leads us to the `models.py` file:

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    style = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    brewer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='All Grain')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1')
    batch_size = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    boil_size = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    boil_time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    efficiency = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=75.0)
    ibu = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    abv = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    notes = models.TextField(default='')
    carbonation = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    primary_age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    secondary_age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    __fermentables = []
  
    @classmethod
    def create(cls,attr):
        recipe = cls()
        # do something with the book
        for k in Recipes._meta.fields:
            if  k.name in attr:
                setattr(recipe,k.name,attr[k.name])
        return recipe
    @classmethod
    def addFermentables(self,items):

       for itm in items:
           
           self.__fermentables.append(itm)
         
           return self.__fermentables

    @classmethod
    def addHops(self,items):
       for i in items:
           return i

    @classmethod
    def addYeast(self,items):
       for i in items:
           return i

    @classmethod
    def addMashStep(self,items):
       for i in items:
           return i
           

  
class RecipeFermentable(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    extract = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    color= models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    fermentable = models.ForeignKey(Fermentable, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    def create(cls, attr, recipes):
        fermentables = cls()
        # do something with the book
        for k in RecipeFermentable._meta.fields:
            if  k.name in attr:
                setattr(recipe,k.name,attr[k.name])
        return fermentables

class RecipeHops(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    alpha = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    use = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    hop = models.ForeignKey(Hop, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    
class RecipeYeast(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='') 
    form = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='') 
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    yeast = models.ForeignKey(Yeast, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    min_temp = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    max_temp = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    attenuation = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)

class RecipeMiscs(models.Model) :
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    use = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    miscs = models.ForeignKey(Miscs, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class RecipeWater(models.Model) :
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    calcium = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    bicarbonate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    sulfate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    chloride = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    sodium = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    magnesium = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    ph = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    notes = models.TextField()

class RecipeMashstep(models.Model) :
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Infusion')
    step_time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    step_temp = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Now I am assuming that in order to save all of this to the database I have to create a new saveData method or smth like that.

However, I am unsure what to put in this method and in general how to go about saving the data into sqlite database.

Could anyone give me some tips on how I should do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create from the model like this.

```
class RecipesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipes
        fields = "__all__"
```

and you can use it like this

```
form = RecipesForm(request.POST)
form.is_valid()
instance = form.save()
```